# Multi seller for one developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an iTune developer account .

I want to create an applications for my client that uses inpurchases. My client want his name to appear in iTunes as seller, also he wants payments transfered to his bank account.

My question is: How I can do that. Should I create a new iTunes developer account for him? Or I can do that in my account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one account only has one bank info.So you should create a new account to do this. Or you can change your bank info to his if you don't need this.